# What is the difference between root and chroot?

Tags: linux, software-installation

Is there any different between `root` and `chroot` in Linux? Can anyone please explain them?

Comment: Those aren't remotely the same thing.  Have you [looked](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Root_directory) [them](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Root_user) [up](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chroot)?

Answer (score 5):

*chroot* is an operation, it changes the apparent root directory for the current running process and it's children.

*root* is an account that by default has access to all commands and files on a Linux (Unix based) system.

*root directory* is the highest directory in a hierarchy.

Answer (score 1):

`root` directory refers to `/` which you can take as the root of the filesystem. It contains directories such as home, var.

`chroot` is the command to change the root directory i.e. changing the `/` for different user.

For eg.

`$ chroot /media`

will change the `root directory(/)` to `/media`

This is generally used in services like ftp to allow any user to access only a subtree of the whole directory tree. Thus it provide restrictions upto which a user can traverse.